# Is given statement indeed true?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, rational-numbers

I saw saw the statement I am trying to prove in "a proof of lub property" in a Mathematics Stack Exchange post. The statement I am trying to prove is :

$∃\ b ∈ \mathbb {R},(b < a\
\text {      AND    }$

$\text {Set of all rationals to the left of}\ b = A)$

where $A$ is the set of all rationals to the left of $a ∈ Q$

---

Is this statement indeed true ?

I get the Theorem is false

---

Below is a proof of lub property I got online:

**The author uses $\subset$ as $\subseteq$.** Also notice the difference by font that $\mathscr{C}$ is a class, while $C$ a set.

---

**Definition**. A cut in $\Bbb{Q}$ is a pair of subsets $A,B$ of $\Bbb{Q}$ such that

1. $A\cup B=\Bbb{Q},\quad A\ne\emptyset,\quad B\ne\emptyset,\quad A\cap B=\emptyset.$
2. $a\in A \land b \in B \implies a\lt b.$
3. $A$ contains no largest element.

**Definition**. The cut $x=A|B$ is less than or equal to the cut $y=C|D$ if $A\subset C$.

---

**Theorem**. If $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb{R}$ and is bounded above then in $\Bbb{R}$ there exists a least upper bound for $S$.

**Proof**: Let $\mathscr{C}\subset\Bbb{R}$ be any non-empty collection of cuts which is bounded above, say by the cut $X|Y$. Define
$$C=\{a\in\Bbb{Q}: \stackrel{?_1}{\text{for some cut }}A|B\in\mathscr{C},a\in A\},D=\text{the rest of }\Bbb{Q}.$$
It is easy to see that $z=C|D$ is a cut. Clearly, it is an upper bound for $\mathscr{C}$ since the "$A$" for every element of $\mathscr{C}$ is contained in $C$. Let $z'=C'|D'$ be any upper bound for $\mathscr{C}$. By the assumption that $A|B\le C'|D'$ for all $A|B\in\mathscr{C}$, we see that the "$A$" for every member of $\mathscr{C}$ is contained in $C'$. Hence $C\subset C'$, so $z\le z'$. That is, among all upper bounds for $\mathscr{C}$, $z$ is $\stackrel{?_2}{\text{least}}$.

---

What I don't get is, it is written right after the definition of $C$ :

It is easy to see that

$z=C|D$ is a cut.

Why is it easy to see...

Comment: This is not true.  There is always a rational $c$ with $b<c<a$.  Just take $n$ large enough so that $10^{-n}<(a-b)$ and take $c=a-10^{-n}$.

Comment: Is this question like asking "does there exist a real number left to a rational $r$ but greater than the previous rational of $r$"

Comment: No...it's asking if there is always  a rational between two distinct reals.  Well, in this case we are told that the larger of the two reals is rational itself, but the stronger claim is true as well.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a "previous rational" relative to any number.

Comment: The usual order on the rationals is [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order). Notice that the midpoint of any two rationals is rational.

Comment: Isn't $A=C$ by definition of $C$ ?